# Configure list of items to send to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I want the user to be able to construct a list of items client-side in a form and then send the entire list to the server when the form is submitted.

Each item has several properties that can be set.  For example, here's an Order model:

```
class Order
{
    int Id;
    string Description;
    Guid UserId;
    string Product;
}
```

The user should be able to add and configure as many orders as they want before submitting the form.

I thought I could do this with the Telerik grid using InCell editing.  Unfortunately, the list of available options for each field will change based on the value chosen for other fields.  I couldn't make this work with InCell editing because I couldn't access the other ui elements from my javascript event handlers.

I also tried to do this with normal InLine editing, but the only item returned is the new Order to be added.  I couldn't access the GridModel to add the new Order.  I don't want to persist the Order list until the user is done editing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If I go with the solution of making my own list, I have this problem with cascading comboboxes.  Each combobox has a name like "UserId_0" based on what index it is in the list.

But now how do I get the downstream list?
Here's my two comboboxes:

```
 <td>
        @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("UserId_" + i.ToString())
            .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.UserIds, "Id", "Name"))
            .Placeholder("Select UserId...")
            .AutoFill(true)
            .CascadeTo("Product_" + i.ToString())
            .SelectedIndex(0))
 </td>
 <td>
       @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("Product_" + i.ToString())
            .AutoFill(true)
            .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("GetProducts", "Order"))
            .Placeholder("Select Product...")
            .SelectedIndex(0))
 </td>
```

And my Controller method looks like this.  It's hacky as hell, but how do I access the value otherwise?

```
    public JsonResult GetProducts(Guid? UserId)
    {
        // Hack!
        ValueProviderResult userResult = ValueProvider.GetValue("UserId");
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            userResult = ValueProvider.GetValue("UserId_" + i);
            if (userResult != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (userResult != null)
        {
            // Get list of products based on value
            return Json(new SelectList(productList, "Id", "Name"));
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not waste your time to achieve this with the some widget - better check how to send [collection of items to the server](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) and implement your own form with checkboxes or so.

If you want to go with some of the widgets - you can try the Grid in a way similar to this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/checkboxesajax).

Comment: Ah, this sounds way more what I want to do.  How do I implement cascading comboboxes though?  When I specify what Controller method to call to populate the combobox, I specify a parameter with the same name as the parent combobox.  So if I want to have a combobox named "UserId" that stores the Order value, the method I'd define to have it cascade to another combobox would be like: JsonResult GetProducts(int UserId).  But when I do the list, the names are all like: "UserId_0".  How can I get my model binder to pass the right value in?

Comment: Put a better explanation in the original question.